# What exactly PyCharm Django Test run configuration do

Tags: python, django, testing, pycharm

I have a custom test command in my Django project:

```
class Command(test.Command):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super(Command, self).add_arguments(parser)
        parser.add_argument(
            "--fit",
            action="store_true",
            help="Fit persistent tests instead of checking them.",
        )

    def handle(self, *test_labels, **options):
        if options["fit"]:
            ...
        super(Command, self).handle(*test_labels, **options)
```

It works when running from the console, e.g. `python manage.py test --fit`.

However, when I'm using a PyCharm Django Tests configuration, it does not execute the `handle(...)` method. I can add `--fit` flag as an option and I can't add some random `--qwerty` flag. So, it means that the command is registered. While running in debug mode, I could reach the point in the `add_arguments(...)`, but not in the `handle(...)` (as well as not in the `django.core.management.commands.test.Command.handle(..)`, by the way).

The only problem is that PyCharm executes this command some other way, without calling `handle(...)` method. So the question is - maybe someone know, what PyCharm is actually calling?

**Updated 21.11.2023**

Screenshot of bad configuration that just ignore flag:
[image: Screenshot of bad configuration that just ignore flag]

Screenshot of working configuration (but it's just not tests):
[image: Screenshot of working configuration (it's not tests)]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Pycharm test configuration please?

Comment: @AdamJaamour - done!